# My python list won't flatten no matter what I do... what to do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flatten

I'm trying to flatten a list that is the result of a zip between two lists. For the code I take 19 data values from 99 different web pages. When I zip the two codes, I put the header of each web page in front of the nested data lists of 19. Now I want to flatten the entire list, keeping the same order. I've tried many different flatten codes and nothing gets rid of the square brackets around each individual data list. Help! :)

I've tried itertools, chain, for loops removing subsets - everything that I found the last two days with google searches.

```
population_data = [('Billbrook', ['2350', '2354', '2032', '1783', '1526', '1528', '1235', '1117', '1133', '1210', '1357', '1476', '1452', '1398', '1428', '2176', '2198', '2097', '1992']), ('Billstedt', ['68256', '68064', '68461', '68512', '68119', '68115', '68573', '68936', '68982', '69085', '69306', '69261', '69110', '69570', '69806', '70100', '70234', '70539', '70355']), ('Borgfelde', ['6526', '6469', '6457', '6504', '6460', '6654', '6591', '6565', '6649', '6611', '6556', '6688', '6857', '7085', '6773', '6845', '7461', '7635', '7696']), ('HafenCity', ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '760', '930', '1097', '1582', '1834', '1914', '2093', '2319', '3275', '3627', '4592']), ('Hamburg-Altstadt', ['1993', '1965', '1908', '1843', '1774', '1816', '1949', '2247', '1701', '1673', '1661', '1665', '1660', '1675', '1793', '1879', '2257', '2305', '2272']), ('Hamm', ['35737', '35854', '35793', '35536', '35195', '35443', '35985', '36228', '36662', '36810', '37243', '37607', '37763', '37520', '37948', '38515', '38136', '38716', '38773']), ('Hammerbrook', ['565', '572', '584', '494', '432', '418', '450', '435', '1697', '1673', '1703', '1896', '2119', '2170', '2244', '2454', '4067', '3939', '4323']), ('Horn', ['35522', '35350', '35910', '35971', '36291', '36302', '36490', '36890', '37351', '37677', '37635', '37882', '37599', '37614', '38296', '38253', '38549', '38569', '38799']), ('Kleiner Grasbrook und Steinwerder', ['1376', '1391', '1410', '1445', '1425', '1361', '1351', '1290', '1279', '1190', '1244', '1305', '1431', '1259', '1326', '1414', '1256', '1243', '1239']), ('Neustadt', ['11912', '12106', '11989', '12052', '11856', '11850', '11747', '11706', '11838', '11626', '11856', '12026', '12331', '12301', '12372', '12586', '12657', '12719', '12920']), ('Rothenburgsort', ['8006', '8047', '8063', '8092', '8181', '8180', '8241', '8660', '8938', '8650', '8637', '8751', '8876', '8992', '9092', '9138', '9137', '9225', '9268']), ('St.Georg', ['10191', '10239', '9940', '10298', '10245', '10388', '10551', '10586', '10666', '9980', '10279', '10443', '10554', '10466', '10682', '10736', '10814', '11055', '11384']), ('St.Pauli', ['26660', '26094', '26776', '26923', '26829', '27035', '27612', '27706', '21703', '21099', '21469', '21704', '22058', '22392', '22433', '22535', '22595', '22501', '22436']), ('Veddel', ['4693', '4603', '4592', '4708', '4776', '4875', '4927', '4944', '4909', '4852', '4847', '4856', '4836', '4709', '4707', '4704', '4632', '4667', '4632']), ('Waltershof und Finkenwerder', ['11833', '11685', '11689', '11637', '11578', '11600', '11634', '11633', '11709', '11666', '11690', '11709', '11718', '11662', '11721', '11733', '11729', '11765', '11808']), ('Wilhelmsburg', ['46125', '47180', '47857', '47847', '48322', '48957', '49132', '49851', '49803', '50091', '50472', '50731', '51171', '52372', '52892', '53764', '55074', '54169', '54068'])]
```

If I used itertools, for example, it cuts out the parentheses, but the square brackets always remain. I printed the length of the list and it's the number of neighborhood headers plus 1 for each data list.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by unzipping `population_data` into a tuple of names and a list containing tuples of numbers.

We then iterate over both names and numbers and join them together in their own sublist

Then we finally we flatten all the sublists into one big list

```
population_data = [('Billbrook', ['2350', '2354', '2032', '1783', '1526', '1528', '1235', '1117', '1133', '1210', '1357', '1476', '1452', '1398', '1428', '2176', '2198', '2097', '1992']), ('Billstedt', ['68256', '68064', '68461', '68512', '68119', '68115', '68573', '68936', '68982', '69085', '69306', '69261', '69110', '69570', '69806', '70100', '70234', '70539', '70355']), ('Borgfelde', ['6526', '6469', '6457', '6504', '6460', '6654', '6591', '6565', '6649', '6611', '6556', '6688', '6857', '7085', '6773', '6845', '7461', '7635', '7696']), ('HafenCity', ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '760', '930', '1097', '1582', '1834', '1914', '2093', '2319', '3275', '3627', '4592']), ('Hamburg-Altstadt', ['1993', '1965', '1908', '1843', '1774', '1816', '1949', '2247', '1701', '1673', '1661', '1665', '1660', '1675', '1793', '1879', '2257', '2305', '2272']), ('Hamm', ['35737', '35854', '35793', '35536', '35195', '35443', '35985', '36228', '36662', '36810', '37243', '37607', '37763', '37520', '37948', '38515', '38136', '38716', '38773']), ('Hammerbrook', ['565', '572', '584', '494', '432', '418', '450', '435', '1697', '1673', '1703', '1896', '2119', '2170', '2244', '2454', '4067', '3939', '4323']), ('Horn', ['35522', '35350', '35910', '35971', '36291', '36302', '36490', '36890', '37351', '37677', '37635', '37882', '37599', '37614', '38296', '38253', '38549', '38569', '38799']), ('Kleiner Grasbrook und Steinwerder', ['1376', '1391', '1410', '1445', '1425', '1361', '1351', '1290', '1279', '1190', '1244', '1305', '1431', '1259', '1326', '1414', '1256', '1243', '1239']), ('Neustadt', ['11912', '12106', '11989', '12052', '11856', '11850', '11747', '11706', '11838', '11626', '11856', '12026', '12331', '12301', '12372', '12586', '12657', '12719', '12920']), ('Rothenburgsort', ['8006', '8047', '8063', '8092', '8181', '8180', '8241', '8660', '8938', '8650', '8637', '8751', '8876', '8992', '9092', '9138', '9137', '9225', '9268']), ('St.Georg', ['10191', '10239', '9940', '10298', '10245', '10388', '10551', '10586', '10666', '9980', '10279', '10443', '10554', '10466', '10682', '10736', '10814', '11055', '11384']), ('St.Pauli', ['26660', '26094', '26776', '26923', '26829', '27035', '27612', '27706', '21703', '21099', '21469', '21704', '22058', '22392', '22433', '22535', '22595', '22501', '22436']), ('Veddel', ['4693', '4603', '4592', '4708', '4776', '4875', '4927', '4944', '4909', '4852', '4847', '4856', '4836', '4709', '4707', '4704', '4632', '4667', '4632']), ('Waltershof und Finkenwerder', ['11833', '11685', '11689', '11637', '11578', '11600', '11634', '11633', '11709', '11666', '11690', '11709', '11718', '11662', '11721', '11733', '11729', '11765', '11808']), ('Wilhelmsburg', ['46125', '47180', '47857', '47847', '48322', '48957', '49132', '49851', '49803', '50091', '50472', '50731', '51171', '52372', '52892', '53764', '55074', '54169', '54068'])]

#Unzip population data into list of names and numbers
name, *li = zip(*population_data)

#name = ('Billbrook', 'Billstedt', 'Borgfelde', 'HafenCity', 'Hamburg-Altstadt', '...
#li = [(['2350', '2354', '2032', '1783', '1526', '1528', '1235', '1117', '1133', '1210', '1l......

#Join the name and numbers in a list
res = [[name[idx]]+li[0][idx] for idx in range(len(name))]
#res = [['Billbrook', '2350', '2354', '2032', '1783', '1526', '1....

#Join all sublists together
concat_list = [j for i in res for j in i]
print(concat_list)
```

The output will be

```
['Billbrook', '2350', '2354', '2032', '1783', '1526', '1528', '1235', '1117', '1133', '1210', '1357', '1476', '1452', '1398', '1428', '2176', '2198', '2097', '1992', 'Billstedt', '68256', '68064', '68461', '68512', '68119', '68115', '68573', '68936', '68982', '69085', '69306', '69261', '69110', '69570', '69806', '70100', '70234', '70539', '70355', 'Borgfelde', '6526', '6469', '6457', '6504', '6460', '6654', '6591', '6565', '6649', '6611', '6556', '6688', '6857', '7085', '6773', '6845', '7461', '7635', '7696', 'HafenCity', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '760', '930', '1097', '1582', '1834', '1914', '2093', '2319', '3275', '3627', '4592', 'Hamburg-Altstadt', '1993', '1965', '1908', '1843', '1774', '1816', '1949', '2247', '1701', '1673', '1661', '1665', '1660', '1675', '1793', '1879', '2257', '2305', '2272', 'Hamm', '35737', '35854', '35793', '35536', '35195', '35443', '35985', '36228', '36662', '36810', '37243', '37607', '37763', '37520', '37948', '38515', '38136', '38716', '38773', 'Hammerbrook', '565', '572', '584', '494', '432', '418', '450', '435', '1697', '1673', '1703', '1896', '2119', '2170', '2244', '2454', '4067', '3939', '4323', 'Horn', '35522', '35350', '35910', '35971', '36291', '36302', '36490', '36890', '37351', '37677', '37635', '37882', '37599', '37614', '38296', '38253', '38549', '38569', '38799', 'Kleiner Grasbrook und Steinwerder', '1376', '1391', '1410', '1445', '1425', '1361', '1351', '1290', '1279', '1190', '1244', '1305', '1431', '1259', '1326', '1414', '1256', '1243', '1239', 'Neustadt', '11912', '12106', '11989', '12052', '11856', '11850', '11747', '11706', '11838', '11626', '11856', '12026', '12331', '12301', '12372', '12586', '12657', '12719', '12920', 'Rothenburgsort', '8006', '8047', '8063', '8092', '8181', '8180', '8241', '8660', '8938', '8650', '8637', '8751', '8876', '8992', '9092', '9138', '9137', '9225', '9268', 'St.Georg', '10191', '10239', '9940', '10298', '10245', '10388', '10551', '10586', '10666', '9980', '10279', '10443', '10554', '10466', '10682', '10736', '10814', '11055', '11384', 'St.Pauli', '26660', '26094', '26776', '26923', '26829', '27035', '27612', '27706', '21703', '21099', '21469', '21704', '22058', '22392', '22433', '22535', '22595', '22501', '22436', 'Veddel', '4693', '4603', '4592', '4708', '4776', '4875', '4927', '4944', '4909', '4852', '4847', '4856', '4836', '4709', '4707', '4704', '4632', '4667', '4632', 'Waltershof und Finkenwerder', '11833', '11685', '11689', '11637', '11578', '11600', '11634', '11633', '11709', '11666', '11690', '11709', '11718', '11662', '11721', '11733', '11729', '11765', '11808', 'Wilhelmsburg', '46125', '47180', '47857', '47847', '48322', '48957', '49132', '49851', '49803', '50091', '50472', '50731', '51171', '52372', '52892', '53764', '55074', '54169', '54068']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
from itertools import chain

population_data = [('Billbrook', ['2350', '2354', '2032', '1783', '1526', '1528', '1235', '1117', '1133', '1210', '1357', '1476', '1452', '1398', '1428', '2176', '2198', '2097', '1992']), ('Billstedt', ['68256', '68064', '68461', '68512', '68119', '68115', '68573', '68936', '68982', '69085', '69306', '69261', '69110', '69570', '69806', '70100', '70234', '70539', '70355']), ('Borgfelde', ['6526', '6469', '6457', '6504', '6460', '6654', '6591', '6565', '6649', '6611', '6556', '6688', '6857', '7085', '6773', '6845', '7461', '7635', '7696']), ('HafenCity', ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '760', '930', '1097', '1582', '1834', '1914', '2093', '2319', '3275', '3627', '4592']), ('Hamburg-Altstadt', ['1993', '1965', '1908', '1843', '1774', '1816', '1949', '2247', '1701', '1673', '1661', '1665', '1660', '1675', '1793', '1879', '2257', '2305', '2272']), ('Hamm', ['35737', '35854', '35793', '35536', '35195', '35443', '35985', '36228', '36662', '36810', '37243', '37607', '37763', '37520', '37948', '38515', '38136', '38716', '38773']), ('Hammerbrook', ['565', '572', '584', '494', '432', '418', '450', '435', '1697', '1673', '1703', '1896', '2119', '2170', '2244', '2454', '4067', '3939', '4323']), ('Horn', ['35522', '35350', '35910', '35971', '36291', '36302', '36490', '36890', '37351', '37677', '37635', '37882', '37599', '37614', '38296', '38253', '38549', '38569', '38799']), ('Kleiner Grasbrook und Steinwerder', ['1376', '1391', '1410', '1445', '1425', '1361', '1351', '1290', '1279', '1190', '1244', '1305', '1431', '1259', '1326', '1414', '1256', '1243', '1239']), ('Neustadt', ['11912', '12106', '11989', '12052', '11856', '11850', '11747', '11706', '11838', '11626', '11856', '12026', '12331', '12301', '12372', '12586', '12657', '12719', '12920']), ('Rothenburgsort', ['8006', '8047', '8063', '8092', '8181', '8180', '8241', '8660', '8938', '8650', '8637', '8751', '8876', '8992', '9092', '9138', '9137', '9225', '9268']), ('St.Georg', ['10191', '10239', '9940', '10298', '10245', '10388', '10551', '10586', '10666', '9980', '10279', '10443', '10554', '10466', '10682', '10736', '10814', '11055', '11384']), ('St.Pauli', ['26660', '26094', '26776', '26923', '26829', '27035', '27612', '27706', '21703', '21099', '21469', '21704', '22058', '22392', '22433', '22535', '22595', '22501', '22436']), ('Veddel', ['4693', '4603', '4592', '4708', '4776', '4875', '4927', '4944', '4909', '4852', '4847', '4856', '4836', '4709', '4707', '4704', '4632', '4667', '4632']), ('Waltershof und Finkenwerder', ['11833', '11685', '11689', '11637', '11578', '11600', '11634', '11633', '11709', '11666', '11690', '11709', '11718', '11662', '11721', '11733', '11729', '11765', '11808']), ('Wilhelmsburg', ['46125', '47180', '47857', '47847', '48322', '48957', '49132', '49851', '49803', '50091', '50472', '50731', '51171', '52372', '52892', '53764', '55074', '54169', '54068'])]
result = []
for elem in chain.from_iterable(population_data):
    if isinstance(elem, list):     #Check if element is list object
        result.extend(elem)        #Extend result
    else:
        result.append(elem)       
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I exactly do not know how do you want to flatten it, the below code will do row wise and column wise flattening.

```
# Flattening
flattened = list(map(lambda t : [t[0]] + t[1], population_data))

# Flattened data printing
for i in flattened:
    print(i)

print('-' * 40)

# Transposed data printing
for k in zip(*flattened):
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
flattened_list = []
x = [[name] + prices for name,prices in population_data]
for inner_list in x:
    flattened_list.extend(inner_list)

print(flattened_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

### flat list can be made through `reduce` easily.

All you need to use *initializer* - third argument in the `reduce` function.

```py
reduce(
    lambda result, _list: result.append(_list[0]) or result.extend(_list[1]) or result, 
    population_data, 
    [])
```

Above code works for both python2 and python3, but you need to import reduce module as `from functools import reduce`. Refer below link for details.

- [for python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)
- [for python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)